# Unable to loop clicking next page button

Tags: javascript, node.js, nestjs, puppeteer

I am trying to scrape a website (https://rca.cnc.fr/rca.frontoffice/#) using puppeteer and NestJS.

So far I'm able to use a form but the data is returned as a table with multiple pages. I was able to make puppeteer click the next page button once, scrape the content, narrow it down to the data I need on page 1,  page 2 loads, but it won't scrape, extract and click and repeat.

```
import { Injectable } from '@nestjs/common';

import puppeteer from 'puppeteer';

@Injectable()
export class AppService {
  async getOeuvres(): Promise<string[]> {
    // (...) Rest of the code (...)
    // Initialize an array to store the results from all pages
    let allResults = [];
    let isDisabled = false;

    do {
      const payloadPromise = new Promise<any>((resolve) => {
        page.on('response', async (response) => {
          const request = response.request();
          if (
            request.url().includes('/rca.frontoffice/api/search/searchOeuvre') &&
            request.method() === 'POST'
          ) {
            const payload = await response.json();
            resolve(payload);
          }
        });
      });

      const payload = await payloadPromise;
      const extractedData = payload.resultatsRecherche.map((item) => ({
        id: item.id,
        numeroImmatriculation: item.numeroImmatriculation,
        dateImmat: item.dateImmat,
        titre: item.titre,
        refId: item.refId,
      }));

      allResults = allResults.concat(extractedData);
      console.log(allResults);

      isDisabled = await page.evaluate(() => {
        const nextButton = document.querySelector('.mat-icon-button[aria-label="Page suivante"]');
        if (nextButton && !nextButton.hasAttribute('disabled')) {
          (nextButton as HTMLElement).click();
          return false;
        }
        return true;
      });

      if (!isDisabled) {
        // Wait for the click to be processed before waiting for navigation
        await page.waitForTimeout(1000);
        await page.waitForNavigation({ waitUntil: 'networkidle0' });
      }
      await page.screenshot({ path: `screenshot${Date.now()}.png` });
    } while (!isDisabled);

    await browser.close();

    return allResults;
  }
}
```

The do...while runs once since i allResults console logged but  the screenshot is not taken and the code won't loop.

I have tried switching the selector or the selecting method ($/evaluate/xPath) but nothing works.

On page 2, the button is identical, it is only modified on the last page with disabled tag.

Desired ouput would be

```
[
{
id: item.id,
numeroImmatriculation: item.numeroImmatriculation, 
dateImmat: item.dateImmat,
titre: item.titre,
refId: item.refId,
},{...}
]
```

Comment: There's a lot of code here but one thing that looks incorrect on sight is `page.on('response'` which should be `page.once('response'`, or better yet, use `waitForResponse` which is pre-promisified for inline use. Otherwise, with `page.on`, the listeners [will never be removed (unless you do `page.off`, of course) and will just stack over time](https://blog.appsignal.com/2023/02/08/puppeteer-in-nodejs-common-mistakes-to-avoid.html#creating-nodejs-memory-leaks-with-pageon-listeners). Beyond that, can you share the exact output you expect? There may be an easier way to get it than you assume.

Comment: Thanks for your response. I'll look into waitForResponse. I expect an array of JSON objects containing the filtered results. I then want to use id to scrape other pages like https://rca.cnc.fr/rca.frontoffice/consultation/oeuvre/:Oeuvreid and https://rca.cnc.fr/rca.frontoffice/consultation/inspub/:Inscriptionid.

Comment: Please trim your code to make it easier to find your problem. Follow these guidelines to create a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).